# Megamenu goes under the site no matter what

Tags: html, css

So i made an megamenu for my site. 
On the main page it works, with exacly the same code used.
On page with item list it goes under the page and do not response on the position:  `absolute` or any  `z-index`.

Main page, working nice:
https://www.miyou.pl/
But on the item list it goes under whole webpage when trying to navigate in menu:
https://www.miyou.pl/bizuteria

Menu:

````
      <ul class="menu-list large standard">

        <li class="parent" id="hcategory_631">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/bizuteria" id="headlink45" class="spanhover mainlevel">
    <span>BIŻUTERIA</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu level1">
    <ul class="level1 sub-right">
    <li class="parent" id="hcategory_419">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/bransoletki" id="headercategory419" class="spanhover">
    <span>BRANSOLETKI</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>



    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_545">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zlote-zawieszki-serce" id="headercategory545" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszka złota serce</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_546">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zlote-zawieszki-nieskonczonosc" id="headercategory546" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszka złota nieskończoność</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_552">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zawieszka-mis" id="headercategory552" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszka złota miś / zwierzęta</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_547">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zawieszka-gwiazda" id="headercategory547" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszka złota gwiazda</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_544">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zawieszka-beczka" id="headercategory544" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszka złota beczka</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_548">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zlote-zawieszki-koniczyna" id="headercategory548" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszka złota koniczyna</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_549">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/pl/c/Zawieszka-zlota-korona/549" id="headercategory549" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszka złota korona</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_550">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zawieszka-kwiatek" id="headercategory550" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszka złota kwiatek</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_551">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zawieszka-kolko" id="headercategory551" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszka złota kółko</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>                                                    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_542">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zlote-zawieszki-333" id="headercategory542" class="spanhover">
    <span>ZŁOTE ZAWIESZKI 333</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="parent" id="hcategory_543">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/srebrne-zawieszki-925" id="headercategory543" class="spanhover">
    <span>SREBRNE ZAWIESZKI 925</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

                            <div class="submenu level3">
    <ul class="level3 sub-right">
    <li class="" id="hcategory_624">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zawieszki-srebrne-serce" id="headercategory624" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszki srebrne serce</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_625">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zawieszki-srebrne-inne-motywy" id="headercategory625" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszki srebrne inne motywy</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_618">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zawieszki-srebrne-pszczola" id="headercategory618" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszki srebrne pszczoła</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_619">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zawieszki-srebrne-skrzydlo" id="headercategory619" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszki srebrne skrzydło</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_620">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zawieszki-srebrne-gwiazda" id="headercategory620" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszki srebrne gwiazda</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_621">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zawieszki-srebrne-koniczyna" id="headercategory621" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszki srebrne koniczyna</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_622">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zawieszki-srebrne-korona" id="headercategory622" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszki srebrne korona</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_623">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zawieszki-srebrne-kwiatki" id="headercategory623" class="spanhover">
    <span>Zawieszki srebrne kwiatki</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>                                                    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_617">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/srebrne-zawieszki-925-pozlacane" id="headercategory617" class="spanhover">
    <span>SREBRNE ZAWIESZKI 925 POZŁACANE</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>                                                    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>                                                            </li>
                                <li class="parent" id="hcategory_632">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/pl/c/KOLEKCJE/632" id="headlink47" class="spanhover mainlevel">
    <span>KOLEKCJE</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu level1">
    <ul class="level1 sub-right">
    <li class="" id="hcategory_653">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/spinki-do-mankietow" id="headercategory653" class="spanhover">
    <span>SPINKI DO MANKIETÓW</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="parent" id="hcategory_468">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/art-deco-bizuteria-srebrna" id="headercategory468" class="spanhover">
    <span>KOLEKCJA ART DECO</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

                            <div class="submenu level2">
    <ul class="level2 sub-right">
    <li class="" id="hcategory_608">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/bransoletki-art-deco" id="headercategory608" class="spanhover">
    <span>Bransoletki Art Deco</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_609">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/kolczyki-art-deco" id="headercategory609" class="spanhover">
    <span>Kolczyki Art Deco</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_610">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/naszyjniki-art-deco" id="headercategory610" class="spanhover">
    <span>Naszyjniki Art Deco</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>                                                    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_537">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/pl/c/Trendy-Jesien-Zima-20192020/537" id="headercategory537" class="spanhover">
    <span>Trendy Jesień Zima 2019/2020</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_606">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/halloween-2019" id="headercategory606" class="spanhover">
    <span>PROMOCJA HALLOWEEN 2019</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>                                                            </li>
                                <li class="parent" id="hcategory_613">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/pl/c/KOMPLETY-Z-GRAWEREM/613" id="headlink44" class="spanhover mainlevel">
    <span>KOMPLETY Z GRAWEREM</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu level1">
    <ul class="level1 sub-right">
    <li class="" id="hcategory_654">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/komplety-ze-zlota" id="headercategory654" class="spanhover">
    <span>KOMPLETY ZE ZŁOTA</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_655">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/komplety-ze-srebra" id="headercategory655" class="spanhover">
    <span>KOMPLETY ZE SREBRA</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>                                                            </li>
                                <li class="parent" id="hcategory_595">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/bizuteria-na-prezent" id="headlink40" class="spanhover mainlevel">
    <span>BIŻUTERIA NA PREZENT</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu level1">
    <ul class="level1 sub-right">
    <li class="" id="hcategory_603">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/bizuteria-na-walentynki" id="headercategory603" class="spanhover">
    <span>Biżuteria na prezent na walentynki</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_604">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/prezent-dla-swiadkowej" id="headercategory604" class="spanhover">
    <span>Biżuteria na prezent dla świadkowej</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_612">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/pl/c/Bizuteria-na-prezent-na-Chrzest-Swiety/612" id="headercategory612" class="spanhover">
    <span>Biżuteria na prezent na Chrzest Święty</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_596">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/prezent-dla-mamy" id="headercategory596" class="spanhover">
    <span>Bizuteria na prezent dla mamy</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_597">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/prezent-dla-przyjaciolki" id="headercategory597" class="spanhover">
    <span>Biżuteria na prezent dla przyjaciółki</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_598">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/prezent-dla-babci" id="headercategory598" class="spanhover">
    <span>Biżuteria na prezent dla babci</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_599">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/prezent-dla-dziewczyny" id="headercategory599" class="spanhover">
    <span>Biżuteria na prezent dla dziewczyny</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_600">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/pl/c/Bizuteria-na-prezent-slubny/600" id="headercategory600" class="spanhover">
    <span>Biżuteria na prezent ślubny</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_601">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/prezent-dla-zony" id="headercategory601" class="spanhover">
    <span>Biżuteria na prezent dla żony</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>                                                            </li>
                                <li class="parent" id="hcategory_467">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zegarki" id="headlink36" class="spanhover mainlevel">
    <span>ZEGARKI</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu level1">
    <ul class="level1 sub-right">
    <li class="" id="hcategory_535">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zegarki-meskie" id="headercategory535" class="spanhover">
    <span>ZEGARKI MĘSKIE</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_536">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zegarki-damskie" id="headercategory536" class="spanhover">
    <span>ZEGARKI DAMSKIE</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    <li class="" id="hcategory_651">
    <div class="menuh3">
    <a href="/zegarki-maserati" id="headercategory651" class="spanhover">
    <span>ZEGARKI MASERATI</span>
    <img src="/public/images/1px.gif" alt="" class="px1">
    </a>
    </div>

    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>                                                            </li>
    </ul></div></li></ul> ```



    ```Partial CSS used (It's SaaS shop code so i can't move too much in html, got a bit of space in css but cant paste whole code)
    .menu .innermenu .menu-list {
        overflow: hidden;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        height: initial;
        border: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: space-around;

}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your ".main" class is out of your ".wrap" class.

Hence on all the other pages, an overflow-x:hidden  is being applied to the wrap and hiding the menu. 
It looks like it is under the page but there is a scroll bar for the top menu.

Put your .main under your .wrap and you will be fine.